# Web Deploy does not update SQL database schema changes

Tags: sql, deployment, web

I am newer to Visual Studio 2012 and MVC4, and have a development project of a website using C# and MVC4 and SQL server 2012.

The Publish using web deploy works for the website portion of the project, but it does not automatically update the database portion (schema). If I right click the database portion of the project in VS2012 and click Publish, then the database schema is updated properly. I am only interested in schema updates. What could be wrong?

I programmed my development system to use Web Deploy 3.0. Here is a summary of my configuration:

1. Computer running win8 x64
2. SQL Express 2012 as my database server, running as the default instance (i.e. at localhost, NOT as .\SQLEXPRESS)
3. IIS Express 8 as my webserver, using the "Default Web Site" site (localhost)
4. Visual Studio 2012 Pro using MVC4 and C#
5. Web Deploy 3.0
6. The latest dates are all applied to the software

I programmed an SQL server user WDeployAdmin for managing the database updates and gave it full permissions over the database being used for the website. I also tried using Integrated Security (my administrator login) but that does not help.

I can correctly update the Default Web Site (views and controllers etc) using the Publish feature in VS2012 which uses Web Deploy 3.0.

When I use the Test Connection feature of the publishing setup options, it correctly connects to the database, and that certainly works fine when I do a separate Publish DB operation (right-click DB project, click Publish, and then pick my profile) for that part of my project.

So why doesn't the standard website Publish feature include the database schema updates? The standard website Publish always shows an empty change to database when the schema changes (e.g. a table or a stored procedure).

I have read through much MS docs but nothing is apparent to me.

Any help is appreciated,

Bruce

Comment: Any solution for this?